# How do I use jQuery .on() to handle click event for a newly inserted dialog link?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-on

I have an existing link to a jQuery dialog that works as it should. But when I try to insert a new dialog link, using .on() to select an existing div, the link does not produce the dialog, but rather simply links to the page.

Can someone help to show how this should be done?

Here is a code sample:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("button").click(function(){
        $("<p><a href='a.html' class='mdialog' name='mine' title='mine' >new link</a></p>").insertAfter("button");
    });

    // this works to produce a dialog for an existing link
    $('.mdialog').each(function() {
        var $link = $(this);
        var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
            .load($link.attr('href'))
            .dialog({
                resizable: false,
                modal: true,
                autoOpen: false,
                closeOnEscape: true,
                position: 'center',
                title: $link.attr('title'),
                buttons: {
                    "Close": function() {
                      $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    }
                }
            });

        $link.click(function() {
            $dialog.dialog('open');

            return false;
        });

    });


  $("#mydiv").on("click","a",function(){

      alert("I'm clicked"); // link click is being handled

    // same code as above does not produce a dialog
        $('.mdialog').each(function() {
            var $link = $(this);
            var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
                .load($link.attr('href'))
                .dialog({
                    resizable: false,
                    modal: true,
                    autoOpen: false,
                    closeOnEscape: true,
                    position: 'center',
                    title: $link.attr('title'),
                    buttons: {
                        "Close": function() {
                          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                        }
                    }
                });

            $link.click(function() {
                $dialog.dialog('open');

                return false;
            });

        });

  });

});

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="mydiv">

<p><a href='a.html' class='mdialog' name='mine' title='mine' >existing link</a></p>

<button>Insert a new paragraph with anchor element after this button</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The a.html is just a very simple message:

```
<p>this should be a dialog message!</p>
```

The **EDIT** below does seem to allow the newly injected dialog to work properly.  It now #1. eliminates the .each loop, as Jamie suggested, and #2. removes the $link.click() handler to open the dialog, and #3. adds an event.preventDefault() to prevent the page from actually being linked instead of the dialog:

```
  $("#mydiv").on("click","a",function(event){
    //alert("I'm clicked"); // link click is being handled

        var $link = $(this);
        var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
            .load($link.attr('href'))
            .dialog({
                resizable: false,
                modal: true,
                autoOpen: false,
                closeOnEscape: true,
                position: 'center',
                title: $link.attr('title'),
                buttons: {
                    "Close": function() {
                      $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    }
                }
            });

        //$link.click(function() {
            $dialog.dialog('open');

        //  return false;
        //});

event.preventDefault();
```

});

Answer (score 0):

To me there is nothing wrong with your on selectors.

You might want to remove the trailing `"`

```
   //Wrong
   <div id='mydiv'">
   //Corrent
   <div id="mydiv">
```

On this note, while not necessary to avoid confusion I would use only double quotes on all attributes.

**Edit**
See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hutber/8JwPj/) This will get on working. Now as for you wanted a dialogue to work on every single you won't want to loop through every single `$('.mdialog') you'll want to add it to the newly created item:

```
 //Inside here: 
 $("button").click(function(){
    $('<a href="a.html" class="mdialog" name="mine" title="mine" >new link</a>').insertAfter("button");
    //Add new dialog
 });

 //Set up the click event for the dialogue. 
 $("#mydiv").on("click",".mdialog",function(){
    alert("I'm clicked"); // li
    return false;
 });
```

I've never used jQuery UI but this is how i would set things up.

Comment: Yes, thanks. It did not help with the dialog though. Any idea why the dialog code doesn't work?

Comment: Should the .on function be passing something that the .each function needs?

Comment: Thanks Jamie, let me try the dialog with something closer to what you suggest.